# Inherit and rename the table from default setting

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-authentication

I would like to rename the default table comes from Django.
Meta does copy the table but the columns are totally difference
How can i over come with it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does not copy the table: it simply performs inheritance, by making a pointer that refers to the *parent* table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `Session` is a concrete model. What here happens is that you specify you want to *inherit* the `Session` table. This is implemented in the SQL layer by making a new table that contains, besides the extra fields, a `OneToOneField` to the parent table, and furthermore this acts as a primary key as well. For more information on how Django handles model inheritance, see the section on [*Multi-table inheritance* in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

If you want to implement your own session model, you should inherit from the [**`AbstractBaseSession`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.base_session.AbstractBaseSession). This is an *abstract* model that has as fields `sesion_key`, `session_data` and `expire_date`. You can then override or "monkey patch" the [**`get_model_class`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py#L19-L24) of the `SessionStore`.

Comment: Actually, I would like to rename all the default table. So what should I do? The original applications are so good that I would like to use after all the names are being adjusted~

Comment: @WKenny: well normally you can not just "monkey patch" the database name. So unless you patch the source code of your local Django installation, that is not possible, or at least not without a lot of "tricks", that likely can break some logic. Why exactly do you *need* to rename the database table?

Comment: Sadly, I would like to use Django, but I have to insert all the table into an existing database that's why I need to rename it.

Comment: Besides, I tried to edit all the names in the Lib.site-packages by adding/changing the db_table label. It always return Django couldn't find the related table...

Comment: @WKenny: well I tried editing `env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/models.py`, and then ran `makemigrations`, and it wrote a migration "Rename table for session to django_blabla", if one later migrates, then the table is renamed.

Comment: how can you trigger makemigrations after edited models.py(lib.site-packages.django.contrib.sessions.models)?
I tried but it return no changes detected

Comment: @WKenny: you edited the one in the virtual environment you use? I've tested this on Django-3.0 and Django-2.2 and these both work.

Comment: Willem truly thanks to you! i found out the reason why I can't makemigrations is due to the virtual environment. Once i start the activate in cmd and try makemigrations it works like a charm! All the default table being rename but also with the default functions like Admin Auth etc.